# How to iterate list of urls using request.get?

Tags: python, loops, python-requests

I have such code:

```
url = "https://www.reformagkh.ru/opendata/export/"
regions = ["150", "101"]
csv_files = []
for region in regions:
    result = requests.get(url, params={"t":region})
    zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(result.content))
    for filename in zf.namelist():
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            file = zf.open(filename)
            csv_files.append(file)
            if len(csv_files) == 1:
                reader = csv.reader(TextIOWrapper(file, 'utf-8'))
                for row in reader:
                    print(row)
            else:
                print("Error")
```

I have 2 links, where located some unzip csv files and I should open them and read. The main question is how work with list of urls and open them step by step?
When I am trying to debug and fix it, I have 400 error and problem with loop. Could somebody give me advise how to handle it?

I should open and handle such links:
['https://www.reformagkh.ru/opendata/export/150',
'https://www.reformagkh.ru/opendata/export/101']

Comment: Could you describe the '400 errors and problem with loop' ?

Comment: You seem to already know how to loop over the regions, so what was the problem with iterating over the urls as well?

Comment: When I am on step `for region in regions' I get response 404

Comment: But every link works if I try to get response without loop

Comment: why you use "arams={"t":region}"? you need just to add 150 and 101 to url and not "?t=150".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prepare the `url` in the loop instead of passing `region` as `params`.

Use `f-strings` to prepare the url as for Python 3.6+:

```
for region in regions:
    url_cur = f"{url}{region}"
    result = requests.get(url_cur)
```

Use `format()` if you are using python version less than 3.6:

```
for region in regions:
    url_cur = "{}{}".format(url, region)
    result = requests.get(url_cur)
```

---

You also need to create the `csv_files` list newly for each url.

The complete code would be:

```
url = "https://www.reformagkh.ru/opendata/export/"
regions = ["150", "101"]
for region in regions:
    cur_url = f"{url}{region}"
    result = requests.get(cur_url)
    zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(result.content))
    csv_files = []  # create a new list everytime
    for filename in zf.namelist():
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            file = zf.open(filename)
            csv_files.append(file)
            if len(csv_files) == 1:
                reader = csv.reader(TextIOWrapper(file, 'utf-8'))
                for row in reader:
                    print(row)
            else:
                print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regions = ["150", "101"]
csv_files = []
for region in regions:
    url = "https://www.reformagkh.ru/opendata/export/%s" % region
    result = requests.get(url)
    zf = ZipFile(BytesIO(result.content))
    for filename in zf.namelist():
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            file = zf.open(filename)
            csv_files.append(file)
            if len(csv_files) == 1:
                reader = csv.reader(TextIOWrapper(file, 'utf-8'))
                for row in reader:
                    print(row)
            else:
                print("Error")
```

I think it is much easier with %s. I often use the same method.